# How to hide php warning in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, warnings

My yii2 web application is hosted on shared server.

it is showing php warning - `" PHP Core Warning – yii\base\ErrorException`
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library `'/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/imagick.so' - libMagickWand.so.2:`

cannot open shared object `file: No such file or directory"`
now i want to disable php warning in my **yii2** application how to achive that?

Comment: I would suggest that you report this to your Hosting Company and get them to fix the error, rather than trying to hide it

Comment: Why hide important information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by changing two parameters in index.php file.

1) Setting `YII_DEBUG` to `false`

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
```

2) Setting `YII_ENV` to `prod` from `dev`

```
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');
```

Answer (score 2):

Comment the following 2 lines in your entry script (index.php)

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

Further, you can also disable the warnings at PHP level by setting `error_reporting` to appropriate value as per the documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Answer (score 1):

Update public/index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

When working on your script, i would advise you to properly debug your script so that all notice or warning disappear one by one. So you should first fix that warning message.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to check all error notice  and warning.

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_startup_errors","1");
 ini_set("display_errors","1");
```